# How do I make it so that its me vs. 10 enemy engineers on the blue team?

Tags: team-fortress-2

How do I make it so that its me vs. 10 enemy engineers on the blue team?
I tried this

```
sv_cheats 1
mp_autoteambalance 0
tf_bot_keep_class_after_death 1
tf_bot_add 10 engineer red easy
```

but it did whatever it wanted to anyway and put random classes on each team...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valve added a new, hidden cvar in the Meet Your Match update two years ago that makes bots always choose certain classes instead of just being random.

The cvar is `tf_bot_spawn_use_preset_roster`. You can apparently change this as long as `sv_cheats` is set to 1.

Edit: Having said that, have you tried `tf_bot_force_class engineer` ?